# How to retrieve the list of mailboxes from Office 365 using ExchangeService

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, .net-standard

I have a task at hand of importing Users (not Contacts, but Mailbox users) from Office 365. I am restricted to use ExchangeService API only.

From the ExchangeService API I can tell there's no direct way to do that. I tried scanning all folders recursively hoping to get some hidden 'users' folder but no luck.

The only way I found was this:

- call ExchangeService.BrowsePeople;
- call ResolveName on each of the Personas returned;
- filter out results leaving name resolutions with Mailbox.MailboxType == MailboxType.Mailbox.

It kind of does the trick (at least, seems so), but seems too complicated and most important, too slow. And I suspect that under the hood it goes to Active Directory still.

Is it possible to do this easier using ExchangeService or should I insist on using some newer API like Graph which seems to have this functionality built-in?

Comment: Your better of just using the Graph API it will be faster,more secure and you also don't need to waste an Exchange licence.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. And by the way, my workaround solution didn't work properly anyway. So, now I took this code as a sample:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-v2

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like to use [GetSearchableMailboxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.getsearchablemailboxes(v=exchg.80).aspx) method, although that method requires the eDiscovery role and only works on Exchange 2013 and newer versions.